# Is there specific verbiage required to close out an engine logbook and start a new one?

Tags: faa

The plane's engine logbook is now full, victim of decades of individual printed stickers, each one occupying a full page. As a result, we need to get an additional logbook.

Is there specific phrasing the FAA likes to see for closing out an old engine/airframe/propeller logbook and starting a new one?